# Machine Check Exception MSI PE60

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

I recently bought msi prestige and it seems to be giving me BSOD Machine check exception. I am really worried right now and this is new machine.

I have tried updating drivers but still it didnt seem to solve the issue.
is this normal or something to be worried about my msi brand new laptop?.

Really need help. thanks

Comment: What is the error code (eg 0x0000009c) on the BSOD? If it relates to hardware, it may be worth using the warranty since the device is new.

Comment: the error code is 0x8000000000000002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my MSI PE60 2QE, running under linux, I was getting MCEs (Machine-Check Exceptions I believe it means), which are supposed to be processor errors.

They went away after I upgraded the BIOS to the latest available. I suspect the BIOS upgrade also upgrades the Intel processor microcode.

Answer (score 0):

Machine-check exception is hardware error. You should do memory test, check HDD for bad sectors and check S.M.A.R.T. for errors. Probably faulty hardware.

Comment: but I ran prime95 on full load and it didnt crash. when I went to MSI Service center, they told me its brand new laptop so hardware error is unlikely.

Comment: can you please recommend me softwares for checking those mentioned by you above?

Comment: Memtest86 and HD Tune PRO.

Comment: I ran Windows memory diagnosis tool and no error found

Comment: Windows memory diagnostil tool is weak + it should run for several hours

Comment: and what do you mean check SMART for errors? sorry couldnt get it.

Comment: Open HD Tune PRO, open health tab and if you see any errors or warning your hard drive is probably faulty.

Comment: I see health status is ok.

Comment: Appreciate your help, can you please tell me how to test processor ? when I googled, I found out few people complaining about i7 5700hq processor with machine error exception on new msi laptops.

Comment: Several hours of stability test like Prime95 or Intel Burn Test is great for testing CPU

Comment: Update : After running INTEL Burn Test, it shows CPU is stable.

Comment: Memtest86, prime95, intel burn test, HD tune pro.. all shows stability.. health to ok.. so what could else be the problem??

Comment: Try unigine valley benchmark to verify video card stability

Comment: I have tried funmark and its stable too.. :(. I seem to have fixed this issue by disabling Intel Turbo boost (SpeedStep) in bios.. :( I now have to run at steady speed.. I wish I could run it at turbo boost.

Comment: Furmark is not good for testing stability. Clearly, something is wrong with your computer. It must work 100% stable with turbo enabled. You should return it

Comment: hello sir. But the problem is it has random crashes so I cant prove that to MSI service center. and secondly few other people also with 5700hq intel 5th gen processor is having those crashes. so I think its a bug in that processor. what to do now?.

Comment: https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=259729.0

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/938199/new-computer-cant-run-linux-but-runs-windows-with-no-problems
here are the links from people.. what is ur suggestion on this? and how can I return.. they dont accept returns :(..